# Invalid argument when using sendto

Tags: c, linux, networking

I am trying to send a buffer via UDP sockets in C but I always get an invalid argument error in sendto. I just don't find the error. Could anyone maybe help me. Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
/**/    void    IPCSend(char *pazClientAddress, int iClientPort, char *pazBuffer )
{
    int iSocket;
    /* */
    if ((iSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) != -1)
    {
        int iSendToReturn;
        struct sockaddr_in sinServerAddress;
        struct hostent *pstHost;
        /* */
        pstHost = (struct hostent *)gethostbyname((char *)pazClientAddress);
        /* */
        sinServerAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sinServerAddress.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)pstHost->h_addr);
        sinServerAddress.sin_port = iPortNumber;
        bzero(&(sinServerAddress.sin_zero),8);
        /* */
        fprintf(stdout,"sending '%s' to client '%s:%d'\n",pazBuffer,pazClientAddress,iClientPort);
        iSendToReturn = sendto(iSocket, pazBuffer, sizeof(pazBuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sinServerAddress, sizeof(sinServerAddress));
        /* */
        if(iSendToReturn != -1)
            fprintf(stdout,"%d bytes sent\n",iSendToReturn);
        else
            perror("SendTo");
        /* */
        close(iSocket);
    }
    else
        fprintf(stdout,"could not connect to server\n");
}
```

Comment: Two things about your code: first you forget to convert the port number to network byte order.

The other problem is that you are using `sizeof(pazBuffer)` as the length. This will get the size _of the pointer_ (i.e. 4 or 8 bytes), and not the length of the string.

Comment: I tryed sinServerAddress.sin_port = htons(iPortNumber); before but with no success

Comment: Try stepping through the code in a debugger, and examine all parameters you pass to `sendto` to make sure they are correct.

Comment: Not being very familiar with c debuggers, could you please give me some hint on how to do that. I installed gdb, attached the PID of the running process, but when I don't really see how to get the parameter values. thank you

Comment: A good resource for socket programming: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: Check the [GDB manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/). GDB also has simple help with the `help` command. The commands you will need here is `break`, `step` and `print`.

Comment: Your code is a bit messy with some unnecessary pointer casts, but the first thing I would suggest is checking to ensure that `gethostbyname` doesn't return `NULL`.

Comment: Also, is `iClientPort` in the argument list the same as `iPortNumber`?  Is that just a typo?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  With GCC this throws a number of errors that would hint to where problems may lie.

Comment: For reference, [this](http://pastebin.com/J2pVaWQj) compiles and runs for me without issue.

Comment: Ok, shame on me!!! I guess I wasn't much focused on this one. I think I need to get some days of rest... it was iPortnumber that I initially declared in the main program but which I ended not setting because I refactored my function to get thos values over parameter for them to be reusable. But I must admit I learned alot from you guys on what other problems there could be. I just want to point out that I am still learning so thank you guys for your kindness and for being willing to help. =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you're making the perennial error of novice C programmers: using `sizeof` to get the size of a pointer.  The variable `pazBuffer` is a *pointer*, not an array, so the `sizeof` operator will not return the array length, which is what you want.  Your `IPCSend` function needs to take in the length of `pazBuffer` as a separate parameter:

```
void IPCSend(char *pazClientAddress, int iClientPort, char *pazBuffer, size_t len)
```

As for the error you're getting - it might be related to something else. `Invalid argument` means that one of the parameters you're passing to `sendto` is somehow invalid.  Since I see that you are properly initializing the socket descriptor, the problem might be that the send buffer is somehow not valid - possibly a null pointer or bad address.  This means that the problem is not apparent from the code you posted, and is likely in some code that is calling `IPCSend`.

Comment: Well, I changed sizeof(pazBuffer) to strlen(pazBuffer) thanks for this one. It was more of a copy paste error of some old code I wanted to fix. Now for the error i'm getting, I fprint a trace in the IPCSend function as you can see and there is no error at all there, pazBuffer is correct.

Comment: `strlen(pazBuffer)` is not a good idea since, if pazBuffer is all null bytes, strlen will return 0.  You should follow Charles' advice and pass the buffer length explicitly.

Comment: @jedwards The SO prints out the contents of `pazBuffer` before the `sendto` so we can assume it's a normal zero-terminated string, which means `strlen` will be okay.